# Does ECS use Docker layer cache to speed-up deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Imagine a typical ECS scenario:

1. I deploy task definition 1 which uses MYIMAGE:1.
2. Later I deploy task definition 2 which uses MYIMAGE:2.

The second deployment goes to the same EC2 hosts as the first one.
So theoretically ECS could use Docker layer cache when pulling MYIMAGE:2 from a container registry (this would probably result in a much faster pull).

But does it use it in practice? Is there a way to enable it? Documentation does not seem to mention it.

Comment: What performance are you trying to achieve? Usually tasks starts in about 15seconds, so slowest pareasuringt is actually AWS metrics cloudwatch alarm for autiscaling that has only 1minute or more measuring

Comment: I realize that image pull might not be the slowest part of my ECS deployments, but still... If 15 seconds could be reduced to 10, wouldn't it be worth doing? Layer caching seems like a pretty simple optimization here with no downsides.

Comment: Do you think of something like Google's Kaniko (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds?hl=de#using_kaniko_cache)? If the ECS agent is doing an ordinary pull, isnt't docker only pulling layers which are on top of the lowest which was modified (compared to the local docker image)?

Comment: @MartinLöper never heard of Kaniko before. I'm just asking if ECS uses `docker pull` the same way I use it on my local machine and does not clean-up image cache between deployments, so older layers can be reused when deploying subsequent versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is ecs-agent using the standard docker pull behaviour?

Since the question was refined in the comments above, I try to answer whether the [ecs-agent](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent) is using the standard docker pull mechanics.

- We know from the AWS docs that the configuration parameter is called `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR`. [1]
- AWS ECS uses the ecs-agent on instances to manage containers. Since the tool is open-source, we have to do the work and look for the code which pulls the images. It is hosted on GitHub. [2]
- If we search for the PR which introduced the pull behaviour switch, we find the following: [#1840](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/pull/1348/).
- From there on, we see that the [docker_task_engine](https://github.com/haikuoliu/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/a8a9b988111e5011f5c5c06e6de7070d3aa71d81/agent/engine/docker_task_engine.go#L774) is the starting point. Then, the [docker_client](https://github.com/haikuoliu/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/master/agent/dockerclient/dockerapi/docker_client.go) is called which in turn uses the [go-docker](https://github.com/docker/go-docker/blob/4daae26030ad00e348edddff9767924ae57a3b82/image_pull.go) project to send an [image_create](https://github.com/docker/go-docker/blob/4daae26030ad00e348edddff9767924ae57a3b82/image_create.go) request.
- We can look at the [docker engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#create-an-image) to see that this is a standard image pull.

#### Conclusion

You can customize the ECS docker pull behaviour by telling the ecs-agent when it should fire off a pull request and whether *automated image cleanup* should be enabled or not. When ecs-agent attempts to pull an image from the container registry, it uses the standard docker "create image" request [3].

Finally the docker engine requests a standard image pull from the docker daemon. [4]
If you set the ecs-agent environment variable `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR` to *prefer-cached*, *MYIMAGE:1* is pulled entirely the first time it is used. Subsequently, the same EC2 instance does a docker pull to retrieve *MYIMAGE:2*.

I tried to figure out how [PullImage in docker daemon](https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/master/api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#L78) works under the hood, but I could not find any useful information. I guess it does a **delta update** of the layers which changed between *MYIMAGE:1* and *MYIMAGE:2* (if MYIMAGE:1 is still available - which requires automated image cleanup to be turned off), but I cannot fully confirm it...

The docker FAQs [5] state the following:

> Versioning. [...] Docker also implements incremental uploads and downloads, similar to git pull, so new versions of a container can be transferred by only sending diffs.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html
[2] https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent
[3] https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#create-an-image
[4] https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/master/api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#L78
[5] https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/

Comment: Wow, great effort to find credible references!

I can confirm now that this is correct and AWS ECS uses layer cache on pulls, even when you leave `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR` at `default` value. I confirmed it via 2 more channels:
1) apparently, my company has premium AWS support so I simply asked them;
2) I ran `docker logs <ecs-agent-container-id>` on EC2 instance running my service and verified that using an optimized layer structure (with the same total image size, but last & changing layer is 200kb instead of 70mb) reduces pull time from 2 seconds to 100ms.

Comment: Hah, sorry, I did not realize accepting the answer does NOT award the bounty automatically. Awarded just now!

Answer (score 0):

ecs issues docker pull command on MYIMAGE:1. if your MYIMAGE:2 has same layers of MYIMAGE:1 then docker will use the locally available image layers and just docker pull on MYIMAGE:2 will only pull the metadata not the actual layers.

detailed doc. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/

Comment: What if MYIMAGE:2 has a few first layers same as in MYIMAGE:1 but the last layer is different? Will it reuse the first layers without re-downloading them? From what I could find in Amazon's ECS documentation, it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: yes as per docker pull it will reuse the whatever layers are already pulled as part of MYIMAGE:1 the remaining layers will be pulled. It is more of a docker behavior than ecs